# PHP gettext and non-ANSII charters

Tags: php, utf-8, translation, gettext

I have a PHP web application which is originally in Polish. But I was asked to locale it into Russian. I've decided to use gettext. But I've problem when I'm trying to translate string with Polish special characters. For example:

```
echo gettext('Urządzenie');
```

Display "Urządzenie" in web browser instead of word in Russian.
All files are encoded in UTF-8 and .po file was generated with --from-code utf-8 . Translations without Polish special chars such as

```
echo gettext('Instrukcja');
```

works well. Do you know what could be the reason of this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* the PHP file is in UTF-8 format? To verify, try this:

`echo bin2hex('Urządzenie');`

You should see the following bytes:

`55 72 7a c4 85 64 7a 65 6e 69 65`

Comment: Yes, echo bin2hex('Urządzenie'); prints: 55727ac485647a656e6965